# How to write a Graph Algorithm

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

Trying to come-up with a pseudocode (in latex) for an algorithm that takes two graphs as input - compares each Node in the graph - (i will fill in the comparing function), but returns 0 if they are a node from one graph is equal to the node in the other graph, else returns 1. A node in the graph could be another graph. So the checking is recursive.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: @GWW Yes solved it and implemented it and i do have the python source Code to do this, my problem is the write-up!

Answer (score 0):

What's your mean , comparing graphs ? To Graphs of G1 and G2 are same if all of the vertices

have same weight[value] and |G1| = |G2| . (in Simple Graphs)

Comment: Each Graph has a Nodes N1....Nn - I have attributes/parameters at Each Node. So for each Node(N) in one graph, i compare the attributes/parameters with the other Node from the second graph.  A Node in a graph can also be a graph - So the algorithm is recursive.